# Group table rows in a PHP where clause

Tags: php

I have this SQL query:

```
<?PHP
$Select = SQLSRV_QUERY($conn,"select Unit, WorkDate FROM TABLE GROUP BY WorkDate, Unit");

    ECHO "<table border='1'width='600'>";
    ECHO "<tr>";

        ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
            ECHO "Unit";
        ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

        ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
            ECHO "WorkDate";
        ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

    ECHO "</tr>";

    WHILE ($Fetch=SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY($Select, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    ECHO "<tr>";
        ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
            ECHO $Fetch['Unit'];
        ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

        ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
            ECHO date_format($Fetch['WorkDate'], 'm/d/Y');
        ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

    ECHO "</tr>";
    }//end WHILE

    ECHO "</table>";
    ?>
```

This outputs a table as such:

```html
<table border='1'width='600'>
<tr>

 <TD><CENTER>
  Unit
 </TD></CENTER>

 <TD><CENTER>
  WorkDate
 </TD></CENTER>
</tr>

<tr>
 <TD><CENTER>
  Unit1
 </TD></CENTER>

 <TD><CENTER>
  06/01/2016
 </TD></CENTER>
</tr>

<tr>
 <TD><CENTER>
  Unit2
 </TD></CENTER>

 <TD><CENTER>
  06/02/2016
 </TD></CENTER>
</tr>

<tr>
 <TD><CENTER>
  Unit3
 </TD></CENTER>

 <TD><CENTER>
  06/03/2016
 </TD></CENTER>
</tr>

<tr>
 <TD><CENTER>
  Unit4
 </TD></CENTER>

 <TD><CENTER>
  06/03/2016
 </TD></CENTER>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking to Output the array into separate tables, based on WorkDate so it looks like this:

```html
    <table border='1'width='600'>
    <tr>

     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      WorkDate
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit1
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      06/01/2016
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>
</table>
<BR>
<table border='1'width='600'>
  
      <tr>

     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      WorkDate
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit2
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      06/02/2016
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>
</table>
<BR>
<table border='1'width='600'>
  
      <tr>

     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      WorkDate
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit3
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      06/03/2016
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <TD><CENTER>
      Unit4
     </TD></CENTER>

     <TD><CENTER>
      06/03/2016
     </TD></CENTER>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I know I need to do a grouping, but I don't know how to put that in a while statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($Fetch['WorkDate']!=$lastdate){
    ECHO "</tr>";
    ECHO "</table>";
    ECHO "<BR/>";
    ECHO "<table border='1'width='600'>";
    ECHO "<tr>";
}

$lastdate = $Fetch['WorkDate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Tom/AstroCB!
Here is the final code I used for this answer:

```
<?PHP

//get the records
$Select = SQLSRV_QUERY($conn,"select Unit, WorkDate FROM TABLE GROUP BY Unit, WorkDate");

//Start the table outside of while statement
ECHO "<CENTER>";
ECHO "<TABLE border='1'>";
ECHO "<TR>";
ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";

WHILE ($Fetch=SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY($Select, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

    //Set up the entry date for comparison to $LastDate
    $EntryDate = date_format($Fetch['WorkDate'], 'm/d/Y');

        //If statement decides if a new table is displayed based on if the current displayed date matches the last date in $LastDate
        IF($EntryDate!=$LastDate){


ECHO "</TABLE>";
ECHO "</CENTER>";
ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "<CENTER>";
ECHO "<TABLE border='1'>";

ECHO "<TR>";
ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
    ECHO "Unit";
    ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
    ECHO "Work Date";
    ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";
ECHO "</TR>";


ECHO "<TR>";
ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
    ECHO $Fetch['Unit'];
    ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
    ECHO $EntryDate;
    ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";
ECHO "</TR>";

        }ELSE{

ECHO "<TR>";
ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
    ECHO $Fetch['Unit'];
    ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";

ECHO "<TD><CENTER>";
    ECHO $EntryDate;
    ECHO "<BR>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";
ECHO "</TR>";

        }//ends if/else

//this variable, outside the if/else will keep track of the last entry date for comparison in the if/else       
$LastDate = $EntryDate;

}//end WHILE

//You also need to close off the table, outside the while statement
ECHO "</TABLE>";
ECHO "</TD></CENTER>";
ECHO "</TR>";
ECHO "</TABLE>";
ECHO "</CENTER>";
?>
```

Comment: You should start writing code in lower case.. i.e. echo , if, else